# How to make array keys as values of another array key and how to create a new array from them too in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array called `$request` as follows:

```
   Array
(
    [op] => edit
    [contact_label] => 1
    [80] => on
    [79] => on
    [76] => on
    [74] => on
    [73] => on
)
```

Now what I want to achieve is two things as follows:

1. Create a new simple array having name `$enquiries` which would contain all the numbers (keys from above array) i.e. **73,74,76, 79 and 80**.
2. Create a new key within this array called `[enquiries]` which would hold all the above said numbers. Also remove the current keys with numbers from the $request array.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**Fiddle**](http://codepad.org/0X4jkE7z)

```
<?php
$request = array( 'op' => 'edit'
                ,'contact_label' => 1
                ,80 => 'on'
                ,79 => 'on'
                ,76 => 'on'
                ,74 => 'on'
                ,73 => 'on'
);



$enquiries = array();
foreach($request as $key => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($key)) {
        $enquiries[] = $key;
        unset($request[$key]);
    }
}

$request['enquiries'] = $enquiries;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($request);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [op] =&gt; edit
    [contact_label] =&gt; 1
    [enquiries] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; 80
            [1] =&gt; 79
            [2] =&gt; 76
            [3] =&gt; 74
            [4] =&gt; 73
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$enquiries = array();
foreach($request as $key => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($key) {
        $enquiries[] = $key;
        unset($request[$key]);
    }
}

$request['enquiries'] = $enquiries;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array( 'op' => 'edit'
                ,'contact_label' => 1
                ,80 => 'on'
                ,79 => 'on'
                ,76 => 'on'
                ,74 => 'on'
                ,73 => 'on'
);

foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $key ) ) {
        $array['enquiries'][] = $key;
        unset( $array[$key] );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [op] => edit
    [contact_label] => 1
    [enquiries] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80
            [1] => 79
            [2] => 76
            [3] => 74
            [4] => 73
        )

)
```

Comment: The way I understood the question, OP still wanted the numbers in an array. May have misunderstood though.

Comment: Thanx. I misread that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$enquiries = array();
foreach( $request as $key => $val ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $key ) ) {
        array_push( $enquiries, $key );
        unset( $request[$key] );
    }
}
$enquiries['enquiries'] = $enquiries;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array_keys()` to store the keys of one array into another.

So what you could to do store the keys in your original array would be something like:

```
$request_keys = array_filter(array_keys($request), function($k){ return is_int($k); });
$request['enquiries'] = $request_keys;

$request = array_filter($request, function($k){ return !is_int($k); });
```

Edit: Filters numeric only keys for the enquiries index and also removes the numeric keys from the $requests array after the process.